# How can I enable the user to post a music file in their post using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

My site will enable users to post something like a blog post, but with a audio file attached to it, so that other user can listen to it while reading. I made a dummy post so that I could check a few things and also a simple route.

```
from flask import render_template
from site import app

posts = [{
    'title': 'asdf',
    'text': 'asdf',
    'file': "2.mp3"
}]


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)
```

I also have the home.html template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Site</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>
        {{ post.title }}
    </h1>
    <h2>
        {{ post.text }}
    </h2>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ post.file }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

My logic was simple: if the 2.mp3 file is in the same directory as the home.html file, then the music should play. But it doesn't. I don't really have an idea what should I do. I'm using Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a bit more complex than that because they're is two options.

The first is the "easy one" and what's you're trying to achieve. Having the file in the `static` folder along with the home template and return it to the user via the template.

To achieve that, you just need to modify your template a bit:

```
<source src="{{ url_for('static', filename=post.file) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
```

However, that will not work if the file is not in your `static` folder (i.e. if the user uploads the file himself).

For that, you will need to follow the steps in the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/) and you will probably end up to something close to the following:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from flask import send_from_directory

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', '.mp3'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER

def allowed_file(filename):
return '.' in filename and \
       filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit an empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=file>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
'''


@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                               filename)
```